# How to write a letter asking for permission for something?

Tags: letter

I need to write a letter asking for permission to enter a facility to get my things, which I left during the pandemic. Does anyone know how to write a good letter asking for permission for something?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few ideas that might help.

1. Don't try any form of negotiation or bribery or blackmail, they won't like it. Just say 'please' and wait for a response
2. Compliments are nice but don't overdo it (1-2 at most)
3. Ask nicely
4. Don't keep bugging them, letters can take some time
5. If it's an email, check back in a week if no response. If you're using this weird thing called the postal service then maybe wait a few days longer
6. Keep it short, it shouldn't be a full page unless you're asking for money

Answer (score 0):

1. Be formal.
2. Add a couple compliments, but nothing too much which makes them think of bribery.
3. Use proper grammar, spelling, capitalization, and whatnot.
4. Ask nicely, use manners.
5. Don't resend every day. That's just annoying.
6. Don't ramble on. Short and sweet yet formal and nice is better.
7. Don't pile on the reasons. Go to the point.
8. Be direct but not rude.
9. If they decline, don't try again for a while. Instead, take some time to think, "Why did they decline?" A month or so later, you can try again, with the answer to that question in mind.

Good luck!